# Check a __declspec macro in preprocessor

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

If I have `SOME_MACRO` which is defined as either `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__declspec(dllexport)`, is there a way to check at compile time which one is being used?

I.e. something like this:

```
#if SOME_MACRO == __declspec(dllimport)
// do something
#else
// do something else
#endif
```

---

UPD.
Looking at the answers I'm getting I guess I should be more specific in why I need this.

I'm trying to compile a rather big 3rd party library, which has a function declared as `dllexport` in most parts of their code where it's included. There's however one component in which it's a `dllimport`.

I need to modify the declaration slighly for the `dllimport` case. The switch between the two declarations is not very simple, it is a result of quite a deep tree of `#ifdef` instructions spread across several files. In principle I could dig this info out form these instructions, but to be sure I did it correctly I'd have to try and compile the whole library under several different configurations (each compilation taking a couple hours).

If on the other hand there was a simple way check whether their `SOME_MACRO` is evaluated to import or export, I could test this on a small program quickly and safely put that inside the library.

Comment: `__declspec` isn't a macro, it's a special keyword in the Visual C++ (and compatible) compilers.

Comment: Use the same logic that is determining the value of SOME_MACRO?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the comment and sorry for mixing up the terms. Still, I guess the idea of what I want to be able to check should be clear.

Comment: @AnonMail in principle, that's an option. But that logic was implemented by someone else and is kinda complicated, so I was hoping there might be an easy way to check this at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use

```
#if SOME_MACRO == __declspec(dllimport)
```

`__declspec(dllimport)` is not a valid token for a preprocessor expression.

Your best option is to use another preprocessor macro, such as:

```
// Are we building the DLL?
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
   // Yes, we are.
   #define SOME_MACRO __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   // No. We are using the DLL
   #define SOME_MACRO __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Now, you can use:

```
#if defined(BUILD_DLL)
```

to include conditional code depending on whether you are building the DLL or using the DLL.

---

Practically speaking, that ends to be a little bit more involved.

1. Most projects have more than one DLL. `BUILD_DLL` is not going to work. You will need `BUILD_xxx_DLL` for each DLL you build. Let's say you have two DLLs, utility and core. and an application that depends on both.
2. You may also need to create a static library.

You will need something like the following in every public .h file of the utility library.

```
#if defined(BUILD_UTILITY_STATIC)
   #define UTLIITY_EXPORT
#elif defined(BUILD_UTILITY_DLL)
   #define UTLIITY_EXPORT__declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define UTLIITY_EXPORT__declspec(dllimport)
#endif
```

Of course, you don't want to have to repeat the same code in lots of .h files. You will create a .h file that contains the above and `#include` that in all other .h files.

When building utility.dll, you will need to define `BUILD_UTILITY_DLL` and leave `BUILD_UTILITY_STATIC` undefined.

When building utllity.lib (static library), you will need to define `BUILD_UTILITY_STATIC` and leave `BUILD_UTILITY_DLL` undefined.

Users of utility.dll will leave `BUILD_UTILITY_STATIC` as well as `BUILD_UTILITY_DLL` undefined.

Users of utility.lib (static library) will need to define `BUILD_UTILITY_STATIC` and leave `BUILD_UTILITY_DLL` undefined.

You will need a similar file for core.dll and core.lib.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This `BUILD_DLL` logic is implemented by someone else in my case. And it's a bit too complicated, so I was hoping maybe I could stringify `SOME_MACRO` and then check, or something...

Comment: @SiLiKhon, that sounds promising. You can dig a bit and figure out the equivalent of `BUILD_DLL`. You can use that macro to include your conditional code.

Answer (score 0):

The macro is named by you the DLL creator.

- You want a header file that works in export or import mode.
- A C/C++ file will be used, to create a program, to build the DLL (export).
- Other C/C++ files will be used to call the DLL (import functions).

In the build implementation file a macro, that you name, is defined before the inclusion of the header.
e.g.

```
#define DLLNAME_BUILD_DLL
#include "dll_header.h"
```

In the header, if the macro is defined, the mode is set to export. When using the DLL the macro is not defined and the functions are imported.